# Treating an input (string) as if it was a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have been trying to make a simple code, which reads an input from user. It will check if any of the words from input is a cuss word from a "List" that I created.

The question here is how can I treat my input (message) the string as if it was a 'List' of words to check if any of them == any word from the "cuss words list" using the "For loop".

**here's my code:**

```
input('Enter your message: ')
Message=str(input)
cuss_words=['word_1' , 'word_2' , 'word_3']


for x in Message:
 if x==[cuss_words]:
  print('You have been banned from chat')
```

---

but for some reason after I run it, I don't get the *print message* even after writing a word from the list.

Comment: For starters, you're not taking any input from the user. You need to assign the return value of *calling* `input()` to a variable: `Message = input()`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for x in Message` goes over every individual character rather than words. To do that, try `for x in Message.split(" ")`.

Also, you should put `if x in cuss_words` instead of `if x == cuss_words`

The complete code would be:

```
Message=str(input('Enter your message: '))
cuss_words=['word_1' , 'word_2' , 'word_3']


for x in Message.split(" "):
 if x in cuss_words:
  print('You have been banned from chat')
```

(Also you can combine first two lines by `Message = input('Enter your message: \n')`)

Comment: `str()` around `input()` is perfectly superfluous…

Comment: Please use 4 space indentation. It might not be visually pleasing as the program becomes more and more bigger

Answer (score 0):

you can't use input as an variable. You should first set something=input("your message" ) then str it.

Comment: There's no need to use `str` on something that's already a string.